# Rails public assets won't load in test, but they do load in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

i'm working with some legacy code and i'm having problems with some assets available in dev and not test.  When I export to PDF in dev everything works fine, but when I try in test I get this error:

"No such file or directory - /Users/me/current_projects/foo/public/assets/uri-checkbox-icon.css"

The file is there, but has a number after it like this: "uri-checkbox-icon-0db5de580292128824f2242038cb1"

Does anyone know why that would load in dev, but not test?

Comment: Have you ran `rake assets:precompile` before launching your server?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.

Comment: Do you have an file named `ui-checkbox-icon.css` in your `app/assets/stylesheets` folder? Development might be picking up something else.

Comment: Use `asset_path` helper with the filename to obtain a valid path from the asset pipeline, including the file's fingerprint (that "number").

Answer (score 1):

Try `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and updating your `environments/test.rb` so that `config.serve_static_assets = true`. This should update your asset pipeline configs in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same settings for config.assets.digest in development.rb and in test.rb ?
(see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)
"Fingerprinting" (adding the number after the name of an asset) is enabled by default for production and disabled for all other environments. You can enable or disable it in your configuration through the config.assets.digest.